# Реализация очереди через массив c#

Tags: c#, массивы, очередь

Доброго времени суток, пытаюсь реализовать очередь через массив, на сайте [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.90).aspx) говорится что при добавлении нового элемента емкость должна автоматически увеличиваться, изначальная длина массива у меня равна 0:

```
public string[] data = new string[0];
```

А в методе добавления элемента, для увеличения емкости массива я использую *Array.Resize*:

```
public void Add(string str)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref data, data.Length + 1);

            for (int i = data.Length - 1; i > 0 ; i --)
            {
                data[i] = data[i - 1];
            }

            data[0] = str;
        }
```

В этом методе я сначала увеличиваю длину массива - **Правильно ли я делаю и может быть есть какой-нибудь другой способ ?**
затем я подвигаю се элементы справа - налево и первым элементом ставлю новый, удалять я буду с другой стороны ?
Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я реализовываю(пытаюсь реализовать) очередь через массив? Есть ли какой - нибудь другой способ увеличивать длину массива или так тоже хорошо ? И нужно ли уменьшать длину массива при удалении элемента из очереди ?

Comment: Для очередей есть готовые реализации - FIFO - `System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>` и FILO - `System.Collections.Generic.Stack<T>`. Они вас не устраивают?

Comment: @Monk вполне устраивают, просто моему знакомому задание такое при приеме на курсы давали, реализовать массив, который будет вести себя как очередь, вот мне и интересно стало сделать такое.

Comment: Ну, если вам не удалось нагуглить лучший способ увеличить размерность массива то наверное этот единственный. А вообще я б на вашем месте глянул как клаcc очереди реализован в .Net (глянуть можно декомпилятором ) и сравнил бы с тем, что получилось у вас.

Comment: Есть не то что другой, а более эффективный, в котором потребуется меньше операций, лучше посмотрите стандартную реализацию, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/Queue.cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы не двигать все элементы, имеет смысл рассматривать ваш массив как кольцевой буфер.

Для этого вы должны знать его длину, текущий индекс начала и индекс конца данных. При удалении элемента из начала вы просто увеличиваете индекс начала данных. При добавлении элемента в конец, если индекс конца ещё можно увеличить, не залезая за конец массива, то вы его увеличиваете, иначе «зацикливаете» данные, делая индекс конца нулём. Только в случае, тогда индекс конца начинает «залезать» на начало, понадобиться увеличивать размер несущего массива, и копировать данные.

---

Как подсказывает @rdorn, если вы увеличиваете несущий массив, имеет смысл увеличивать не на один элемент, а сразу на несколько. Например, на фиксированный процент текущего размера. Или можно придумать более изощрённую стратегию.

Comment: и при увеличении - делать это с заделом на будущее, а не каждый раз на 1. Причем фактор роста можно сделать динамическим в обратной пропорциональности к размеру имеющегося, т.к. 10% от 100 и 100кк это совсем разные 10%

Comment: @rdorn: Точно. `Queue<T>`, кстати, увеличивает каждый раз вдвое, но не меньше, чем на 4: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/queue.cs,200

Comment: кстати в довесок одна из возможных хитрых стратегий может быть такой: у нас есть ограничение на размер массива, достаточно большое, но есть, даже на х64. Возьмем разность верхнего предела и текущего размера, разделим на верхний предел, добавим 1 и получим коэффициент на который нужно умножить текущий размер. При этом без риска на очередном шаге словить OutOfMemoryException. Актуально для быстро растущих больших массивов. На малых массивах или с заведомо медленным ростом можно обойтись фиксированным ростом

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ, позже я сделал коэффициент *capacity* равный двум и после добавления элемента проверял, если последний элемент != null  увеличиваю размер массива в два раза. У меня возник вопрос, если Вам не сложно ответить, а как сделать  из того что у меня "есть" generic, я читал примеры, нужно унаследовать класс от ienumerble class myQueue<T> : ienumerble ,  но для чего такое делать и как правильно класс должен выглядеть ?

Comment: @VladimirKhodakovskey: Вам нужно написать что-то вроде `class Queue<T>` (ну и если хотите, `class Queue<T> : IEnumerable<T>`), и заменить внутри класса `string` на `T` по большому счёту.